# How to configure notary node while running cordapp via IntelliJ

Tags: corda

I want to configure the notary node , for example as non validating. How do I configure it in the cordapp example,NodeDriver.kt file?

I could see the option in build gradle file and run via terminal, but I am specifically looking to run via intellij.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass your own list of notary specs to the driver:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val notaryName = CordaX500Name("MyNotary", "London", "GB")
    val notarySpec = NotarySpec(name = notaryName, validating = false)

    driver(DriverParameters(notarySpecs = listOf(notarySpec))) {
        // Driver logic.
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please help me on how to configure  for BFT consensus also here? I am referring the **samples/notary-demo** of release v3.0 and trying to implement in cordapp example project.

Comment: Hey, could you raise that as a separate question please?