# How to configure the BFT consensus in Cordapp example?

Tags: corda

I am referring the SO link
[How to configure notary node while running cordapp via IntelliJ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53170414/how-to-configure-notary-node-while-running-cordapp-via-intellij)

Can you please help me on how to configure for BFT consensus also in intellij? I am referring the samples/notary-demo of release v3.0 and trying to implement in cordapp example project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot run a BFT notary using the node driver. However, you can start a RAFT notary as follows:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val notaryName = CordaX500Name("MyNotary", "London", "GB")
    val notarySpec = NotarySpec(
        name = notaryName, 
        validating = false, 
        cluster = ClusterSpec.Raft(clusterSize = 3))

    driver(DriverParameters(notarySpecs = listOf(notarySpec))) {
        // Driver logic.
    }
}
```